# After an upgrade, Mongodb Atlas starts thrashing IOPS and page faulting, and very slow queries build up

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-atlas

We are experiencing a sporadic performance issue with Mongodb Atlas, after we upgrade the cluster or when the primary changes. [The upgrade process is automated by the MongoDb Atlas service, and so knowledge of the mechanics of this for us are limited]

Cluster type is:
M30 (8Gb ram)
Upgrading 4.2 -> 4.4
Provisioned IOPS: 1500

After an upgrade (this has happened going from 4.0 -> 4.2 also) we will see alerts on IOPS going above 80% provisioned, and page faults occurring, best explained by the chart:

[image: Metrics showing performance]

Another important observation is that the very slow queries appear to not be utilising indexes appropriately:

For example, this query (slightly snipped)

```
{
  "command": {
    "count": "projects",
    "query": {
      "$and": [
       {
          "account": {
            "$oid": "RETRACTED"
          }
        },
        ....
        ....
        ....
"planSummary": [
    {
      "IXSCAN": {
        "account": 1,
        "hasTemplateChildren": 1,
        "templateParent": 1,
        "lastEditedAt": -1
      }
    },
    {
      "IXSCAN": {
        "templateParent": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "keysExamined": 1604628,
  "docsExamined": 1631743,
```

This suggests that the desired index is being used, but yet over 1.6 million keys and docs are being examined. The entire `projects` table has about 1.9m rows and **any one account has at most 30k rows projects.**

Hopefully this is sufficient information. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There's something missing.  Why was it using an index on templateParent in addition to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update, we have solved this problem and it seems that the issue was with part of the query I left out, posting here for clarity. It seems that the query planner was getting confused because of a particular expression:

```
{
   "$or": [
    {
      "templateParent": {
          "$exists": false
       }
    },
    {
       "templateParent": null
     }
    ]
 }
```

And it was that which was causing essentially the entire index (the one on templateParent) to be scanned as part of the child inputStage.

Changing the expression above to:

```
  {
    "templateParent": null
  }
```

Allows the query planner to do more sensible queries.

If anyone cares to offer a deeper explanation on why this makes the query planner behave better, please do.